# Basic AVG length of a decimal number program

Tags: javascript

It's my first time using stack exchange and getting my code reviewed, so if you find any issues with this post, please tell me. Anyway, I have done a very simple program in JS to find the average length of a decimal number created by a Math.random() function. The program works well, but since I'm new to coding, any improvements on my code would be greatly appreciated.

````
//make a program to see the average of lenght of random decimal numbers, find the lenght of each

var randomNums = [];
var length = [];
var total = 0

//random
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    randomNums.push(Math.random());
}

//length 
for (var i = 0; i < randomNums.length; i++) {
    length.push(randomNums[i].toString().length);
} 

//average
function average() {
   for (var i = 0; i < length.length; i++) {
       total += length[i];
   }
   
    var avg = total / randomNums.length;
    avg = Math.round(avg);

return avg;
}

console.log(average());
//output: 18
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. (Styling) First thing that you should consider is to apply formatting:

   1. Your tabs are not consistent.
   2. In most code styles, you should have a single space between // and text.
2. You should declare variables only when they are started to be used. Do not declare variables at the start of code - that's confusing. (Well, when you are using `var` this makes some sense, but see also recommendation about not using `var`). See https://agiletribe.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/27-dont-declare-variables-at-the-top/ for some explanation.
3. You should avoid imperative for-s and use map/reduce. This makes your code cleaner & composable at cost of a non-significant performance drop. See https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/map-vs-for-loop-2b4ce659fb03 for some explanation.
4. It's better to make function `average` as an independent helper. In order to do that, you need to stop reading global variables & start accepting parameters. By this, you ensure that your helper can be reused in other places.
5. Function `average` has too many lines for no reason. Remove empty lines. Merge dividing + rounding into a single line.
6. It's better not to introduce global variables `randomNums` and `length`. It's better to create functions that generate such things. Then chain calls together. See https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad for some explanation.
7. `var` is bad. Use `let` and `const`. See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/ for some explanation.
8. Delete comments. Comments are worth only when they explain why you are doing things you are doing. In case if you need to explain what you are doing, it's better to create a variable or a function with good name. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/05/best-practices-for-writing-code-comments/ for some explanation.
9. Leverage using of external libraries, like `lodash`.

   - In order to do that you need:

     - either run your application via npm+node (in case if you have troubles with that, google "building console application via node")
     - use bundler like the webpack in the case if you develop a website. See https://webpack.js.org/
     - use online-IDE with the ability to install custom libaries. Like stackblitz. For example, you can see your reworked code sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-jp1rdv?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.js
   - And apply the next changes to your code:

     1. Replace your own `average` with `mean` from `lodash`. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mean
     2. Leverage your code by using `range` from `lodash`. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#range

Final code is here:

```
import { range, mean } from 'lodash';

function generateRandomNumbers() {
    return range(0, 100).map(() => Math.random());
}

function getLengths(array) {
    return array.map(num => num.toString().length);
}

console.log(mean(getLengths(generateRandomNumbers())));
```

Or you can get rid of temporary functions and merge all of that into one call:

```
import { range, mean } from 'lodash';

console.log(mean(
    range(0, 100)
        .map(() => Math.random())
        .map(num => num.toString().length)));
```

You can see these changes applied here one-by-one (in reverse order): https://gist.github.com/vlova/c69e3bd254af87c4acf50d6be44adbb5/revisions

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your answers looks good, enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 2):

### Use functions

Where you have the comments `// random` `//length` and `//average` the bits of code they refer to should be defined as functions, as you have done with `average`.

Give the functions the arguments need to produce the data, and have the function return that data so you don't need to store data in the global scope.

Example converting the 2 tasks `// random` `//length` to functions using function declarations, and cleaning up `average` to use reduce.

```
function randNums(count, nums = []) {
    while (count-- > 0) { nums.push(Math.random()) }
    return nums
}
function numsLen(nums) {
    return nums.map(num => num.toString().length);
}
function average(lengths) {
    return lengths.reduce((total, num) => total + num, 0) / lengths.length;
}
```

You can then call them as follows, with the next function in the step getting the return from the previous.

```
console.log(average(numsLen(randNums(1000))));
```

You can also define functions using expressions, where the unnamed function is assigned to a variable. JavaScript has a shortened function syntax called an [Arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) Arrow function are not identical to [functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) created using the `function` token

```
const randNums = count => new Array(count).fill().map(() => Math.random());
const numsLen = nums => nums.map(num => ("" + num).length);
const average = lens => lens.reduce((tot, num) => tot+ num, 0) / lens.length;
```

<sub>**Note** the the above functions do not contain returns, the `return` is implied. See [Arrow_functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for details.</sub>

Below the arrow functions are identical to above but just add the implied tokens.

```
const randNums = (c) => { return new Array(c).fill().map(() => Math.random()) }
const numsLen = (n) => { return n.map(num => ("" + num).length) }
const average = (l) => { return l.reduce((tot, num) => tot + num, 0) / l.length }
```

<sub>**Note** I have shortened the names just so they fit the CodeReview page.</sub>

### Problem / Bug?

#### Counting the decimal point?

One does not normally count the decimal place when counting digits in a number. `0.1` has two digits not three

When you get the length you need to subtract 1 to ignore the decimal point.

However there is a chance that random will give you a whole number 0 which will not have a decimal point. Thus for that one case you are forced to check that the string length is not 1 before subtracting, or check the number is zero before converting it to a string

This can be done using a [? (Conditional operator)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)

```
const numsLen = nums => nums.map(num => num ? ("" + num).length - 1 : 1);

// same as

const numsLen = nums => {
    nums.map((num) => {
        if (num !== 0) { return num.toString().length - 1; }
        return 1;
    });
}
```

#### Very small numbers

[Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) will give number from 0 to < 1 and many of the numbers in that range can be very small. When JavaScript converts number to a string it will use [Lexical_grammar#Exponential](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Exponential) notation when there are many leading or trailing zeros.

For example the number `0.00000003499165601716925` (25 characters) which is a valid random value is converted to the string `"3.499165601716925e-8"` with 20 characters.

The `"e-8"` means move the decimal point 8 places to the left. If the value was positive then it would mean move 8 places to the right. As random values will never be >= 1 then the exponent will always be negative.

There could be hundreds of leading zeros, eg `1.0e-300` is a very small possible result for [Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

You will need you create a function that parses the number string so that you can count the leading zeros. As the exponential notation will only be for very small values you can ignore the sign of the exponent.

```
const parseNumLen = str => {
    if (str.includes("e")) {
        const [digits, exp] = str.split("e-");
        return digits.length - 1 + Number(exp);
    }
    return str.length;
}
```

The above uses [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to first test if the number contains an exponent. If it does it splits the string into an array of strings using [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). The array is assigned to variables digits and exp using [Destructuring_assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the length is is calculated using [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert the string exp to a number. If you don't convert the string to a number the + operator would convert the result to a string.

For example

```
const [digits, exp] = ("0.3e-10").split("e-");
console.log(digits.length - 1 + exp);         // >> 210 as 2 is converted to "2" by the + 
                                              //    that prefers adding strings when it sees one
console.log(digits.length - 1 + Number(exp)); // >> 12
```

#### Global scope

The names you have used `randomNums`, `length`, `total`, `average` and `i` all exist in the global scope. This means that any code on the page can get access to the variables and means that the code using these names can no longer trust the values they contain. You MUST always be able to trust your data.

To build a good JavaScript coding habit always isolate you code from the global scope. There are many ways to do this but the most effective is to put your code inside an unnamed function that calls its self. Generally referred to as a [Immediately Invoked Function Expression  (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

eg

```
;(()=>{
   /* your code */
})();
```

<sub>**Note** the leading ";" this is to protect your function wrapper from poorly formatted code that may sit above your code</sub>

### Sloppy V Strict

JavaScript has two modes of operation that effect how the code is interpreted / complied and then executed.

1. [Sloppy_mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Sloppy_mode)

   Default mode for standard code and script tags. This mode is called Sloppy Mode not because its sloppy, but rather that it lets you be sloppy.
2. [Strict_mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

   For code that is in a module or has the directive `"use strict"` at the top of the script tag, file, and or function and ensures that you do not make some common coding errors by throwing syntax errors when you write sloppy code.

   Strict code not only forces you to write better code, but that code also runs a little quicker. Making it a JavaScript coding habit to use strict mode is always a win win.

### Rewrite

Using all the points above we can write the code as

```js
;(()=>{
    "use strict";
    const parseNumLen = str => {
        if (str.includes("e")) {
            const [digits, exp] = str.split("e-");
            return digits.length - 1 + Number(exp);
        }
        return str.length - 1;
    }
    const randNums = count => new Array(count).fill().map(() => Math.random());
    const numsLen = nums => nums.map(num => num ? parseNumLen("" + num) : 1);
    const average = lens => lens.reduce((tot, num) => tot + num, 0) / lens.length;

    const nums = randNums(10);
    const aveDigits = average(numsLen(nums));

    console.log(nums);
    console.log("Average number of digits: " + aveDigits);
})();
```

Comment: Nice gotcha about parseNumLen

Comment: Just as a note. Sections global scope and strict mode are required if you aren't using any tooling. If you use bundlers, they will do that for you.